# Existence of non-constant function $f$

Tags: analysis

let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous function.

For arbitrary two real number $a, b$ $(a<b)\\$

Set $S=\left\{f(x)\vert a<x<b\right\}$ has both maximum and minimum.

---

I find $f$ must have local minima, local maxima in interval$(a, b)$ and the local maximum must bigger than $f(a)$  (or $f(b)$) and local minimum must smaller than $f(a)$ (or $f(b)$).

But, to satisfy that conditions, $f$ must have infinitely many local minimum(maximun)s.

I found constant function $f$ satisfies conditions, but I wonder existence of non-constant function.

Is there non-constant $f$ which satisfy that conditions?

Comment: I don't think so. Let $M$ be the global maximum (on some non-degenerate interval) of $f$, attained at $x_1$ and $m$ be the global minimum, attained at $x_2$. Assume $x_1\ne x_2$. WLOG, assume $x_1<x_2$. There must be some $y$ in $(x_1,x_2)$ with $f(y)=M$. Let $z=\sup\{ y\in(x_1,x_2) | f(y)=M\}$. By continuity of $f$, it follows that $f(z)=M $. In order to avoid a contradiction, we must have $z=x_2$; and thus $m=M$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Isn't Weierstrass function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) an example of what OP is looking for? In case it isn't, why not?

Comment: @dfnu It has local extrema on any non-degenerate interval; but, as far as I can gather,  the OP's problem requires a global min and max on any $(a,b)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra You should make that an answer.